# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'.

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hello I'm trying to figure out why switching my compatability mode from 80 to 100 in MSSQL broke my function below?

```
    Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1617.0 (X64)   Apr 22 2011 19:23:43
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition with Advanced Services (64-bit) on
Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
```

Here is my  function:

```
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetRoot] 
(
    @Param1 int 
)
RETURNS varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @ReturnValue varchar(50)
with results as
    (
        select parentouid,net_ouid from net_ou where net_ouid=@Param1
        union all
        select t2.parentouid,t2.net_ouid from net_ou t2 
        inner join results t1 on t1.parentouid = t2.net_ouid where t2.parentouid <> t1.net_ouid
    )   
    select @ReturnValue = net_ou.displayname 
    from  NET_OU RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    results ON net_ou.net_ouid = results.ParentouID where results.parentouid=results.net_ouid

    RETURN @ReturnValue

END
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try throwing a semi colon in front of the with:

```
;with results as
    (
        select parentouid,net_ouid from net_ou where net_ouid=@Param1
        union all
        select t2.parentouid,t2.net_ouid from net_ou t2 
        inner join results t1 on t1.parentouid = t2.net_ouid where t2.parentouid <> t1.net_ouid
    )
```

Give [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163346.aspx) a read to understand why you need to do that.  Snipit:

> However, if the CTE is not the first statement in the batch, you must
>   precede the WITH keyword with a semicolon. As a best practice, I
>   prefer to prefix all of my CTEs with a semicolon—I find this
>   consistent approach easier than having to remember whether I need a
>   semicolon or not.

Personally, I don't do it for **every** CTE, but if that makes things easier for you it won't hurt anything.

Comment: LOL so true!  Also may want to point out to OP it's the declaration, so if you declare multiple `CTE`s only the `WITH` should have the semicolon (I've seen people confused on this before).

Answer (score 6):

Add a semicolon before `WITH`:

```
;with results as
    (
        select parentouid,net_ouid from net_ou where net_ouid=@Param1
        union all
        select t2.parentouid,t2.net_ouid from net_ou t2 
        inner join results t1 on t1.parentouid = t2.net_ouid where t2.parentouid <> t1.net_ouid
    )   
    select @ReturnValue = net_ou.displayname 
    from  NET_OU RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    results ON net_ou.net_ouid = results.ParentouID where results.parentouid=results.net_ouid

    RETURN @ReturnValue

END
```

CTE declarations need to be the first command in the batch.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you adopt the practice of ending all statements with a semicolon. This is part of the ANSI standard and will help you when need to work on another database. SQL Server are moving towards this in any case. Many more commands require semicolons now in SQL Server 2012.

E.g.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetRoot] 
    (@Param1 int)
RETURNS varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ReturnValue VARCHAR(50)
    ;
    WITH cteResults 
    AS (SELECT parentouid
              ,net_ouid 
          FROM net_ou 
         WHERE net_ouid=@Param1
         UNION ALL
        SELECT t2.parentouid,t2.net_ouid 
          FROM net_ou t2 
         INNER JOIN results t1 
                 ON t1.parentouid = t2.net_ouid
         WHERE t2.parentouid <> t1.net_ouid )   
    SELECT @ReturnValue = net_ou.displayname 
      FROM net_ou 
     RIGHT JOIN cteResults 
             ON net_ou.net_ouid = results.ParentouID
     WHERE results.parentouid=results.net_ouid
    ;   
    RETURN @ReturnValue
    ;   
END
;
GO
```

As an added bonus it makes you queries a crap load easier to read. ;-)